# Utilizar this em evento onclick para setar estilo css em elemento específico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Seguinte galera, estou tentando setar um estilo css em um elemento específico quando clicar em um botão, já fiz algo parecido mas agora está setando pra todos os elementos que possuem a classe que utilizei no seletor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os botões ao lado de fora do número são botões pra aumentar ou diminuir.

Quando eu clico neles preciso que apareça o ícone de atualizar igual o circulado, porém apenas do produto no qual cliquei no botão e não dos dois.

```
                    <div class="cart-qty">

                       /*Botão de Aumentar Qtd*/

                        <div class="qty-ctl">
                            <button title="<?= $this->__('Decrease') ?>" type="button" data-role="change_cart_qty" class="decrease decrease-sidebar-cart" data-qty="-1"></button>
                        </div>

                        <input type="text" pattern="\d*(\.\d+)?" name="" id="qinput-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" data-link="<?php echo $this->getAjaxUpdateUrl() ?>" data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" data-cart-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getSku(); ?>" class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text" name="" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" <?php if ($this->isOnCheckoutPage()) echo 'disabled'; ?> maxlength="12" />

                       /*Botão de Diminuir Qtd*/

                        <div class="qty-ctl">
                            <button title="<?= $this->__('Increase') ?>" type="button" data-role="change_cart_qty" data-qty="1" class="increase increase-sidebar-cart" ></button>
                        </div>

                         /*Botão de atualizar*/

                        <button id="qbutton-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" data-update data-cart-item-update class="button quantity-button update-cart-item" style="opacity: 0">
                            <?php echo $this->__('ok'); ?>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                /*Função para fazer aparece o botão*/

                <script>

                    $j('document').ready(function(e) {
                        $j( ".increase-sidebar-cart, .decrease-sidebar-cart").click(function() {
                            $j(e).(".update-cart-item").css("opacity", "1");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: Amigo, no lugar de usar o jquery para mudar a propriedade opacity, tente utilizar o JS puro pegando pelo ID do botão assim `document.getElementById("qbutton-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>").style.opacity = "1";`

Comment: Valeu Murilo, ajudou bastante, utilizei o js puro como indicou porque o ` qbutton-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>` eu passei por parâmetro através de um onclick que coloquei nos botões e recuperei na função, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Para deixarmos tudo organizado, vou passar esse meu comentário para resposta e depois apaga-lo, aí se você puder coloque este seu comentário nele, informando o que foi feito, e marque como correta, assim ajuda a outras pessoas que estejam procurando pela mesma dúvida que você, o que acha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, no lugar de usar o jquery para mudar a propriedade opacity, tente utilizar o JS puro pegando pelo ID do botão assim:

```
document.getElementById("qbutton-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>").style.opacity = "1";
```